# using blueprint css within a jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, blueprint-css

I'm using blueprint to do a complex form layout that involves jquery-ui tabs, but when I try to use the blueprint span-x divs within the jquery-ui tabs, the formatting gets all screwy....

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#blahblah"><span>blah blah</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#blahblahblah"><span>blah blah blah</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="blahblah">
    <div "class="span-8 last">
      <dl>
       <!--some input boxes-->
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i take the "class-span-8 last" out, the page works as expected.  Any help / ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to try giving each tab/div the blueprint "container" class.

Comment: But wouldn't that cause overflow?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that it's probably because the div overflows. Start with span-1 and work your way up.